# Setting an image as the background of a GeoGraphics image

Tags: graphics, image

It's easy to set the background of a GeoGraphics image to black, e.g.,

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon[Entity["Country", "Canada"]],
  GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", "Centering" -> {0, -97}},
  Background -> Black]
```

[image]

How do I replace the black background with an image? I've tried replacing `Background -> Black` with `GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"Image", image}]` but without success.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The `Prolog` and `Inset` solution works nicely for my application. Thank you, @Mr.Wizard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Prolog

You can use [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) and [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) which avoids rasterizing the `GeoGraphics`:

```
lena = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

GeoGraphics[Polygon[Entity["Country", "Canada"]], 
 GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", "Centering" -> {0, -97}}, 
 Prolog -> Inset[Image[lena, ImageSize -> 500]]]
```

[image]

#### RemoveBackground

[`RemoveBackground`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveBackground.html) works on `GeoGraphics`; you can use [`Overlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html) or [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to combine:

```
geo = GeoGraphics[Polygon[Entity["Country", "Canada"]], 
   GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", "Centering" -> {0, -97}}];

lena = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

Overlay[{lena, RemoveBackground @ geo}]
```

[image]